# Eloquent selfreferencing hierachie to json

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying Eloquent now with high expectations.

I have a category tree. 
Everything works fine. But now I want to return the whole tree as json. Therefore I'm doing:

```
$categories =  Category::whereNull('parent_id')->get()->toJson();
```

And only get the adam and eve nodes.

```
[{"category_id":1,"name":"Boats","slug":"boats","parent_id":null},     
 {"category_id":2,"name":"Paddles","slug":"paddles","parent_id":null}]
```

Which is good basically. How to integrate the childs recursivly? No "native" eloquent way for that?

Tree like this:

```
select * from categories;
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
| category_id | name           | slug           | parent_id |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
|           1 | Boats          | boats          |      NULL |
|           2 | Paddles        | paddles        |      NULL |
|           3 | Kayaks         | kayaks         |         1 |
|           4 | Canoes         | canoes         |         1 |
|           5 | Carbon Paddles | carbon-paddles |         2 |
|           6 | Vajda K1       | vajda-k1       |         4 |
|           7 | Dagger RPM     | dagger-rpm     |         3 |
|           8 | Kober Viper    | vober-viper    |         2 |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

and a model like that

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
    protected $fillable = array("name", "slug", "parent_id");
    public $timestamps = FALSE; 

    // each category has many subcategories
    public function childs() {
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
    }

    // each category belogs to one parent category
    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
```

Comment: Chris, first of all recursive mysql queries not a good idea. I suggest you to choose nested data set model for database structure. It has so many benefits to handle your nodes. You can read http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ this article. In addition that you can find community packages for this kind of works. I've used https://github.com/etrepat/baum this package before. There is "allLeaves" method that's what you need and it's works like a charm. If you interested in how is work, just check the source code. Happy coding :)

Comment: Oh, really? Done that many times without an ORM. Worked for me. Not good? I'll read. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know there is no native way to get a recursive result from eloquent directly.
For the first level you would use:

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with('childs')->get()->toJson();
```

For the next level (and likewise further on):

```
$categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->with(['childs' => function ($query) {
        $query->with('childs');
}])->get()->toJson();
```

Using [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) you'll be able to build your own PHP `giveMeMyCatTree()` methode.

Does this help?